# Where did Instruments go in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: xcode, instruments, xcode4.3

I have just updated from 4.2 to Xcode 4.3 and "Instruments" is no longer there.

I tried to run it from Launchpad but was informed that this is not possible because Instruments is in the trash bin.

Xcode 4.3 uninstalled 4.2 but it seems it did not bother installing a new version of Instruments.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can launch Instruments from within Xcode. It is no longer in the **/Developer** folder but in **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer**.

From the menu bar, choose **Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Instruments**.

[image]

Comment: Err...from where? I cannot see it in the app bundle.

Comment: @Krumelur - You can launch Instruments from within Xcode, then right click on it and choose **Options > Keep in Dock**.

Comment: Yes, that is clear. I would like to get it back into Launchpad. This requires it (or at least a link) to be in Applications.

Comment: Can't you find it in **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer**? Right click on **Xcode.app** and choose **Show Package Contents** to access its subfolders.

Comment: This took me longer than I'd care to admit to find.

Answer (score 7):

If your goal to profile your code with Instruments after all, choose menu "profile" from your project then Xcode launches Instruments as you probabbly expect.

[image: Xcode Project>Profile]
[image: Instruments]